# VB.NET: Large Array - Faster Alternative?

Tags: arrays, database, vb.net

I am working with a very large csv file that keeps on growing. Basically, my program checks if a specific ID number is present. If it is present, is uses the data in the array. If it is not present, it downloads the data from the internet and adds it to the array.

Here is my array:

```
Public Shared ClientSideData(0 To 99999, 0 To 5) As String '"MLS Number","GLA","Latitude","Longitude","Year Built","Acreage","ClientSideNext"
```

Here is a sample line from the csv file:

```
"21633662","1631","40.298488","-74.052182","1950","0.1791"
```

And here is the very simple function I use to check if the MLS # is present:

```
Function ClientSideLoc(mls As String) As Integer
    For i = 0 To GlobalVariables.ClientSideCount - 1
        If GlobalVariables.ClientSideData(i, 0) = mls Then
            Return i
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    Return -1
End Function
```

The CSV file adds upwards of 500 entries per day sometimes. It is growing fast. Once it surpasses 100,000 entries, my current plan is to go back and start overwriting the early entries with new ones. I have a feeling this ClientSideLoc function is going to end up slowing my program down more than if I just downloaded the missing info from the internet every time.

I am curious if there is a faster alternative? What would you recommend? Would a database be a better option? I am not familiar with them. Thank you

Comment: Using a CSV parsing tool like CSVHelper will be much faster and much cleaner - data can be stored as typed data rather than relegated to string.

Comment: Can this have an unlimited number of entries? Due to memory concerns, I am currently limiting my entries to 100,000

Comment: Your current search is linear in the number of items in ClientSideData.  At the cost of more memory consumption, you could add an index of `mls` to location in the array, e.g. using a `Dictionary (Of String, Integer)`.  This would do the lookup in roughly constant time.  If you use a database and put an index on the field corresponding to `mls`, then the database will be doing something like this for you to speed lookups.

Comment: Database would definitely be faster. I would suggest to erase the oldest entries instead of replacing them, it would be faster. You might not need to load the whole csv, just one line at a time. An other option is to have 1 csv per day but that depends on the needs of the business.

Comment: You showed seven column names, but only six fields. What about the "CientSideNext" field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dictionary solution is what I was looking for. Doesn't help my memory issue, but that's okay. Answers this question for now. Thank you Craig!

Comment: What memory issue?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest processing the csv file daily into a table in a database. Even something like Access can work for this. Then you can query the database table and not worry about memory consumption.

Also: this looks like about 76 bytes per record, if you have a CSV reader that lets you be efficient and parse columns to appropriate types:

MLS#: 8-char string * 4 bytes per unicode character
GLA: 4 byte int
Lat: 8 byte double
Long: 8 byte double
Year: 4 byte int
Acre: 8 byte double
Object reference: 12 byte object reference overhead

At 100,000 records, that's still less than 10MB. Memory use won't be a problem. Even the worst-case scenario where everything is a string works out to less than 20MB total.

Given the memory really won't be a problem, you should be fine to use a `Dictionary(Of String, Listing)`, where `Listing` is a class you create to hold these records.